# Will you have to write an app twice if you use React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

From my understanding of the concept of React Native, it is centered around building mobile apps. But does React Native work **in Browsers** especially on desktop computers and laptops, not just stand-alone apps? Does that mean that you will have to build an app as a website for browsers and a stand-alone app for mobile?

Comment: What about this: https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/react-native-for-windows

Comment: React-Native apps can be run in the browser if all the libraries you use support this feature and you are building your app for the browser too. Since this is somewhat of a new feature, a lot of libraries won't work in the browser so you will be restricted when trying to program 3 in 1 with react native